# Error "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" " java Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, parsing, netbeans, joptionpane

i'm doing a practice program with polimorfism and things like that and i have the error "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: """
this is the code

```
package functions;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author angel
 */
public class Sumas extends interface.Sum {
 interface.Sum sum = new interface.Sum();
    public void Sum() {
       
         int num1 = Integer.parseInt(sum.jTextField1.getText());
        int num2 = Integer.parseInt(sum.jTextField2.getText());
        int r= num1 + num2;
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The result is : " + r);
    }
}
```

Please help

Comment: Well the error is obvious jTextField1 and JtextFiedl2 are not returning any text.

Comment: user input must always be tested! or it is just empty, or may contain any invalid character (non-digit for example)